# Python 3: search subdirectories for a file

Tags: python, os.path

I'm using Pycharm on a Mac. In the script below I'm calling the `os.path.isfile` function on a file called `dwnld.py`. It prints out "File exists" since `dwnld.py` is in the same directory of the script (`/Users/BobSpanks/PycharmProjects/my scripts`). 
If I was to put `dwnld.py` in a different location, how to make the code below search all subdirectories starting from `/Users/BobbySpanks` for `dwnld.py`? I tried reading `os.path` notes but I couldn't really find what I needed. I'm new to Python.

```
import os.path

File = "dwnld.py"

if os.path.isfile(File):
    print("File exists")
else:
    print("File doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
import os
File = 'dwnld.py'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/BobbySpanks/'):  
    if File in files:
        print ("File exists")
```

---

> `os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)`
>
> Generate
>   the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down
>   or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top
>   (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames,
>   filenames).
>   <sub>[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob) for this:

```
import glob
import os

pattern = '/Users/BobbySpanks/**/dwnld.py'

for fname in glob.glob(pattern, recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        print(fname)
```

A simplified version without checking if `dwnld.py` is actually file:

```
for fname in glob.glob(pattern, recursive=True):
    print(fname)
```

Theoretically, it could be a directory now.

> If recursive is true, the pattern `'**'` will match any files and zero
>   or more directories and subdirectories.

Comment: This probably doesn't need to call `os.path.isfile()`. If glob returned it, then a file exists. I think OP was more interested in existence than file type.

Comment: Yes. It is rather unlike that there is a directory named like this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import os
File = "dwnld.py"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files: # loops through directories and files
        if file == File: # compares to your specified conditions
            print ("File exists")
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31621120/5135450

Comment: 1) Indentation, 2) you don't need `os.getcwd()`, just use `'.'`, its the same thing. 3) `str.isfile()` doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't know why they voted you down, you have my vote up

Comment: change `file.isfile(File)` to just `file == File` (and maybe change the names for claritys sake.)  Other than that, this is the canonical solution

Comment: @UriGoren - I gave three reasons why I downvoted. The most significant of which is his code just flat doesn't work. It generates `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isfile'`

Comment: @Robᵩ, The solution is basically ok, there's a slight error that patric-haugh mentioned, but I see no reason to discourage a user who spent time an effort by punishing him and reducing from his already low reputation.

Comment: @UriGoren Having low reputation shouldn't defend you from getting downvoted for an answer that doesn't work without being edited. Although the downvote should be removed promptly once fixed.

Comment: Corrected and tested, works on my machine. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the Path module built into python and use the glob method of that

Code for that:-

```
import Path
File = "dwnld.py"

pattern = '/Users/BobbySpanks/**/dwnld.py'

for fname in Path(pattern.rstrip(File)).glob(File, recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        print("File exists")
    else:
        print("File doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score -1):

something like this, using os.listdir(dir):

```
import os
my_dirs = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for dirs in my_dirs:
    if os.path.isdir(dirs):
        os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), dirs)
        #do even more
```